# Is it possible to call Automation test class from main activity for to launch test class through intents programatially?

Tags: android

I want to call automation test class from main activity through intents in android .i want to launch the test class programatically.if it is possible means please anybody suggest how to write code programatically launching test class in android..

Comment: What do you mean with launch the class programatically?
Do you mean run and build the app automatically?

Comment: if anybody knows means please do answer..

Comment: i want to run test class not manually pressing run button in android studio but call test class from main activity class so that automation test class will get run(launch)

Comment: hello @chandu i know ur problem ...without run application  u need to automate that class right..?

Comment: yes but programaticaly want to run test class from other main class

Comment: ...k but it is verry tricky ..i think there is no any tools for that

Comment: yeah right but solution will be there .

Comment: I really wait for an idea but seem like it didn't show up

Answer (score 0):

@DerKingsten.. it is not possible to call testclass programaticlly from main activity class?